# how to find perpendicular plane equation

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Point P ($x_1,y_1,z_1$)is known. I want the equation of plane MPQO and plane ABCD.
For plane MPQO,

$\overrightarrow PM$=($x_1,y_1,0$)

$\overrightarrow QM$=($x_1,y_1,-z_1$)

$\overrightarrow PM \times \overrightarrow QM$= ($y_1x_1,-x_1z_1,0$)

the equation of plane MPQO is

$$-y_1x+x_1y=0$$

Now I have no idea where to go after this for plane ABCD.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can divide through by $z_1$ in your equation of $MPQO.$  You don't have to, but it would look cleaner.

Comment: okay. I edit my post.Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Plane ABCD has normal vector $\vec{OQ} (x_1,y_1,0)$, thus has equation

$$x_1x+y_1y+0z=k \ \ (*)$$

Now, for finding constant $k$, you express that $(x,y,z)=(x_1,y_1,0)$ verifies equation (*).

It gives $x_1^2+y_1^2=k$.

Thus the equation of the plane is $$x_1x+y_1y=x_1^2+y_1^2$$